# bash scripting: how to move a string before .<dot> for each line in a file

Tags: linux, bash

file contains:

```
compat-db.x86_64                      4.6.21-17.el6                          
chkconfig.x86_64                      1.3.49.5-1.el6
```

I would like to add prefix `-` before `4.6.21-17.el6` and move this before `.` with bash scripting.

So the output should be:

```
compat-db-4.6.21-17.el6.x86_64
chkconfig-1.3.49.5-1.el6.x86_64
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: Try to solve this on your own and come back when you reach a real roadblock.

Comment: You probably want to use awk for this. Sed would work, too, but would be more cumbersome.

Comment: There are blanks at the end of the first line. Is that true for the real input?

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

```
awk '{ sub(/\./,"-"$2".",$1); print $1 }' file
```

The output:

```
compat-db-4.6.21-17.el6.x86_64
chkconfig-1.3.49.5-1.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: awk '{ sub(/\./,"-"$2".",$1); print $1 }' file  works for me Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GNU-sed solution:

```
sed 's/\.\(.*\)[[:space:]]\+\(.*\)/-\2.\1/'
```

- `\.` matches a dot literally
- `[:space:]` is a POSIX class, in a character class, it matches any whitespace character
- `\+` means "at least once"
- `\(...\)` is used for capturing

Answer (score 0):

BSD Sed & GNU solution:

```
sed -E 's!^([^\s\.]*)(\.[a-Z0-9_^\s]*)[\s]*([^\s]*)[\s]*$!\1-\3\2!g;s! !!g' < yourfile.txt
```

Comment: GNU sed officially understands `-E` as well, by the way. This has inofficially been supported for a while already and is now official, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_002dE).

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for your comment, I updated my answer with slight change as well